# Angular - How to "bind" when "oninput" with "contenteditable span"?

Tags: angularjs, onchange, contenteditable

"`<span contenteditable>{{ line.col2 }}</span>`"

Hello,

This code is good at initialisation but if I edit the span, no bing is send and my array model never updated...

So, I have tried this :

```
<span contenteditable ng-model="line.col2" ng-blur="line.col2=element.text()"></span>
```

But "this.innerHTML" does not exist.

What can I do ?

Thank at all ;-)

Answer (score 4):

you can remove the ng-blur and you will have to add this directive:

```
<span contenteditable ng-model="myModel"></span>
```

---

Here is the directive taken from the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController):

```
.directive('contenteditable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
    require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if(!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

      // Specify how UI should be updated
      ngModel.$render = function() {
        element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
      };

      // Listen for change events to enable binding
      element.on('blur keyup change', function() {
        scope.$apply(read);
      });
      read(); // initialize

      // Write data to the model
      function read() {
        var html = element.html();
        // When we clear the content editable the browser leaves a <br> behind
        // If strip-br attribute is provided then we strip this out
        if( attrs.stripBr && html == '<br>' ) {
          html = '';
        }
        ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank very much ! I didn't know this possibility and it work perfectly.

After some editions (see bellow)

Comment: You should mention that this directive was taken from angular's documentation. Strengthens your answer ;) Its around line 16327 in angular >= 1.2.6

Answer (score 2):

I only will point you to possible solution, then you need to parse/clean HTML better.

```
<span contenteditable data-ng-blur="bar = $event.target.innerHTML">
    {{bar}}
</span>
```

// upd.

Angular events such as click, blur, focus, ... - fired with scope context, e.g. `this` will be current scope.
Use `$event`, be happy.

Comment: Thanks very much ! ;-)
Now i know how to access to my target.
But i have another problem : "the <br> and <div> tags are visibles (parsing fail)"
--> I check the directive solution to see if it's better

Answer (score 0):

Solution with Mirrage and gab help :

```
<span contenteditable="true" ng-model="ligne.col2">{{ ligne.col2 }}</span>


app.directive('contenteditable', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      // view -> model
      element.bind('blur', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          ctrl.$setViewValue(element.html());
        });
      });

      // model -> view
      ctrl.$render = function() {
        element.html(ctrl.$viewValue);
      };

      // load init value from DOM
      ctrl.$render();
    }
  };
});
```

Thank at all ;-)